# dyld[3169]: Library not loaded: @rpath/libtbb.dylib

Tags: python, pycharm, facebook-prophet, prophet

I am trying to use prophet on python to forecast stock data. I could download the package fine through pip install prophet but when i run:

```py
m = Prophet()
m.fit(mydataframe)
```

It gives me this error:

```
RuntimeError: Error during optimization: console log output:

dyld[3169]: Library not loaded: @rpath/libtbb.dylib
  Referenced from: /xxxxxx/xxxxxx/.conda/envs/stockappv3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/prophet/stan_model/prophet_model.bin
  Reason: tried: '/private/var/folders/k7/9pw6q9xx44q19pn4ltz0ywkc0000gn/T/pip-install-pwe0karb/prophet_b21adc17687149baac0676a11064ed80/build/lib.macosx-11.1-arm64-cpython-310/prophet/stan_model/cmdstan-2.26.1/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/tbb/libtbb.dylib' (no such file), '/private/var/folders/k7/9pw6q9xx44q19pn4ltz0ywkc0000gn/T/pip-install-pwe0karb/prophet_b21adc17687149baac0676a11064ed80/build/lib.macosx-11.1-arm64-cpython-310/prophet/stan_model/cmdstan-2.26.1/stan/lib/stan_math/lib/tbb/libtbb.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libtbb.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libtbb.dylib' (no such file)
```

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: I haven't solved this myself yet, but I believe it has to do with running on an M1 processor. Mentioning this in case it helps you, or a future reader

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, installing `tbb` with brew: `brew install tbb` solved the issue for me.

This is on an ARM (M1) mac and I've seen a few other threads not specific to prophet but that did require this library also suggesting installing tdd with brew

Comment: You might've meant tbb?

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with Prophet 1.1 and Mac M1. Use Version `1.0` and Python `3.8`.

This configuration works on my M1:

- prophet `1.0`
- python `3.8.15`

[Further Information](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/2250)